# Should this question about bug reports be closed?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I just failed a Close Review audit for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128050/how-do-i-report-a-severe-bug-to-the-spring-social-facebook-team-login-fails-aft). I voted to close it as "too broad", but the system thinks it's a good question and should stay open.

I disagree, because the question amounts to "how do I report a problem to the Spring team?" It's answered in the comments with a link to a github issue.

I don't think this is a valuable question for SO. Am I off base here?

Comment: Yes, it should: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company). And now it is.

Comment: The question was closed, a patch was submitted and applied to the master branch, just chilling out for a release.

Comment: Aww, he researched his question too well.  Had he left it at "Facebook login bombs, halp" then it would have been on topic.  Lovely.

Comment: maybe it should be reworded to "what should I do about this issue", which would make it both on-topic and (more) useful for future visitors. There are coding answers to that, which existing answer explains.

Comment: @HansPassant Wouldn't that be more on-topic at SuperUser? (Not that I think it would really be on-topic anywhere on SE...)

Comment: @KyleStrand how so, if OP is actually programming the integration?

Comment: @eis I was referring to Hans Passant's hypothetical "Facebook login bombs, halp" question. Though I guess even in that case it could be made clear that this is from a facebook-integration perspective, not a facebook-user perspective.